# Get notification when NSTableView.clickedRow is changed?

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, right-click

I am looking for something like this for the NSTableView, however it doesn't seam to work. I figure i would use this info to modify an NSMenu before it's displayed for rows.

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"tableview.selectedRow" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a better way to do this as well, but one thing you could do that might be a bit better than the solution you proposed is to subclass NSTableView. From your subclass you could then use `[self setAction:@selector(clickedTableView)]` then inside this method you could do `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification...];` and send a notification that way instead. You could then pass `self.clickedRow` in the `userInfo` of the notification.